# Can I check granted permissions in android layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-permissions

is it possible to add a view to layout only if a certain permission is granted?

I am using a QR Code reader library called [QRCodeReaderView](https://github.com/dlazaro66/QRCodeReaderView). I am using the  `com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview.QRCodeReaderView` in my layout.

On Android M and above it would crash the app if the view is in the layout unless the user accepts the permission.

Is it possible that when loading the layout I can make a check and decide to include this view only if permission is granted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some supplement to @CherryPerry's answer:
There is no need for create two different layouts. You can put `ViewStub` with `QRCodeReaderView` into your layout, and call `inflate` only if permission granted:

```
if (permissionGranted()) {
    qrReaderStub.inflate();
}
```

see [more about ViewStub](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html).

---

*Sample:*

```
<!-- qr_reader.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview.QRCodeReaderView
    android:id="@+id/qr_reader"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />
```

```
<!-- your activity or fragment -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ViewStub 
           android:id="@+id/qr_stub"
           android:layout="@layout/qr_reader"
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

```
//your activity class
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ViewStub.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.qr_stub)).inflate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible that when loading the layout I can make a check and decide to include this view only if permission is granted

Yes, you can. Call `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission`. If it's result is `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED`, then permission is granted.

So you can

1. Create instance of `QRCodeReaderView` and add it to layout you created only if permission is granted. Create layout without `QRCodeReaderView` inside, but with `FrameLayout` instead. Put `QRCodeReaderView` inside this `FrameLayout` after permission check if necessary.
2. Make 2 different layouts (one with `QRCodeReaderView` and other without) and call `setContentView` or `inflater.inflate` in `onCreateView` dependent on `checkSelfPermission` result.

I recommend you first one, so you can implement requesting permission. When user grants permission, you add `QRCodeReaderView` to your layout.